# Absolute continuity of joint distribution if all marginals in any basis are absolutely continuous

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Consider a probability distribution $\nu$ on $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. I know that the absolute continuity of the marginals on $x$ and $y$ is not sufficient to imply the absolute continuity of $\nu$, because we could choose a probability measure concentrated on the diagonal $(x,x)$.

But what if I can apply any basis rotation $O\in SO(2)$ and have a promise that for all of these the marginals remain absolutely continuous. Here, the counterexample breaks down as we can rotate such that one basis vector is orthogonal to the diagonal $(x,x)$. Is this sufficient to imply that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous? Or at least that the singular part of the distribution does not affect the marginals?

Comment: Uniform measure on the sphere…